# How to redraw lines in canvas based on treeview item collapse or expand?

Tags: wpf, canvas, data-binding, treeview, wpf-controls

I have a tree view in my WPF view and I have a canvas as well, I am triggering a double click event and passing `ItemContainerGenerator` as a parameter to my command as bellow.

```
<dc:Interaction.Triggers>
   <dc:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
       <dc:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TreeItemDoubleClickCommand}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=treeView, Path=ItemContainerGenerator}"/>
       </dc:EventTrigger>                       
   </dc:Interaction.Triggers>
</dc:TreeView>
```

then I am getting a treeview item position as below

```
private void PerformDoubleClick(ItemContainerGenerator itmGenerator)
{
    var selectedItem = _dirItems.SelectMany(d => d.GetAllChildren()).FirstOrDefault(c => c.IsSelected);

    TreeViewItem tvii = ContainerFromItemRecursive(itmGenerator, selectedItem);

    if (tvii == null) return;
    TreeViewItem tvi = tvii;

    GeneralTransform myTransform = tvi.TransformToAncestor(tvii);

    Point myOffset = myTransform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

    //canvas.Children.Clear();
    var line = new Line();
    line.Stroke = Brushes.LightSteelBlue;

    line.X1 = myOffset.X + tvii.ActualWidth;
    line.X2 = 700;
    line.Y1 = myOffset.Y + tvii.ActualHeight / 2;
    line.Y2 = 300;

    line.StrokeThickness = 2;
    //canvas.Children.Add(line); 
    var fromPoint = tvii.PointFromScreen(new Point()); 
    MappingLines.Add(new MappingLine { From = new Point(fromPoint2.X * -1.00 - 50, (fromPoint2.Y * -1.00 - 55)), To = new Point(X2, Y2), LineColor = GetRandomColor() });

}
```

later the `MappingLines` added as a source to canvas and drawing the lines as below.

```
<ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding MappingDocumentViewModel.RightPanel }" ItemsSource="{Binding MappingLines}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Line X1="{Binding From.X}" Y1="{Binding From.Y}"
                  X2="{Binding To.X}" Y2="{Binding To.Y}"
                  Stroke="{Binding LineColor}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

my question here is how can I redraw the lines when tree view item expands or collapses? currently the lines will be there in the same coordination when I expand and collapse the treeview item,

any suggestion to this problem?

Comment: You want to bind the visibility of `Line` to the `IsExpanded` property of a treeview item. maybe if you keep it as simple as that you have a better chance of finding an answer

Comment: Another note, since you have only one Line, why not use another panel instead of `Canvas`? other panels are confined to their sizes unlike canvas.

Comment: @Bizhan its not a one line, there will be multiple lines along with different colors, once user collapse the tree view item, the lines should also be updates, in my case lines sill remains the same position when the treeview collapse, because the line starting position was taken from tree view item's X,Y coordination.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood your problem. you probably need refresh mechanism. see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986840/wpf-treeview-refreshing

Comment: by the way I don't think this is the best approach. you are binding line X,Y to their absolute coordinations. you might want to reconsider doing that. I would suggest finding a tutorial for this